# Does Asus F8SV supports 1920*1080 resolution through DVI output?

Tags: dvi, vga

Devices:

- Asus F8Sv Laptop (Windows 7 ultimate, GeForce 8600m GT, display driver is 301.42, detected and downloaded from nvidia.com, VGA and DVI output interface)
- Gateway 23 inches LCD monitor (VGA, DVI-D with HDCP, and HDMI input)
- 18 pins DVI cable, VGA cable, both new.

Problems:

When connect laptop to monitor by VGA, resolution is automatically adapted to 1920*1080; but when using DVI connection, resolution on monitor is fixed to 1024*768, which is lower than my laptop default 1280*800. The maximum resolution in windows control panel is only 1024*768, while the Nvidia control panel provides options 1920*1080p and 1920*1080i, but clicking apply button does not work, the resolution just can not change.

Possibly reason I guess:

GeForce 8600m GT does not support 1920*1080 resolution through DVI outputs.

Can anyone confirm it or give the real reason?

---

edit:

Problem solved by buying a HDMI to DVI-D adapter. Using this adapter and a HDMI cable, I can now enjoy 1080p movie.

Comment: The [reference 8800M design](http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_8600M_techspecs.html) appears to be able to output up to 2560x1600 via DVI, and has an integrated 1080p HDTV encoder.  Make sure you have the latest possible drivers.